# How to fix Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 error

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting error at `[InvoiceId]`:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near 'clustured'

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sales_invoice_info
(
   id          int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
   invoiceid   nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   invoicedate Date NULL,
   customer_id int NULL,
   grand_total Float(53) NULL,
   total_paid  Float(53) NULL,
   balance     Float(53),
   PRIMARY KEY clustured ( [invoiceid] ASC)
);
```

Comment: It's a **typo** - it should be **CLUSTERED** (not "clustured" - "e" after the "t" - not a "u"....)

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017), a primary key in SQL Server is automatically created as a clustered index:

> When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint, a unique clustered index on the column or columns is automatically created if a clustered index on the table does not already exist and you do not specify a unique nonclustered index. The primary key column cannot allow NULL values.

So just try removing the `CLUSTERED` keyword:

```
create table tbl_sales_Invoice_info (
    id int Identity(1,1) not null,
    InvoiceId Nvarchar(50) Not Null,
    InvoiceDate date null,
    Customer_id int null,
    Grand_Total float(53) null,
    Total_paid float(53) Null,
    Balance Float(53),
    primary key ([InvoiceId])
);
```

Comment: A terrible suggestion IMO. Tell the computer to do EXACTLY what you want it to do and don't rely on default behaviors that can change depending on factors determined at runtime. And the best solution is to simply spell the appropriate keywords correctly.

Comment: @SMor No, most SQL Server developers would not explicitly spell out clustered for the primary key in a single table.  But good catch on the typo, and I will remember the downvote for later!

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove keyword `Clustered` or just correct the spelling mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sales_invoice_info
(
   id          int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
   invoiceid   nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   invoicedate Date NULL,
   customer_id int NULL,
   grand_total Float(53) NULL,
   total_paid  Float(53) NULL,
   balance     Float(53),
   PRIMARY KEY Clustered ([invoiceid] ASC)
);
```